# Merging json arrays

Tags: python, json

I have 30 .json files that look roughly like this:

```
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "x"
    },
    {
      "name": "y"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
{
      "sender_name": "x",
      "timestamp_ms": 1605269986949,
      "content": "xx",
      "call_duration": 4614,
      "type": "Call"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "x",
      "timestamp_ms": 1605269967718,
      "content": "xx",
      "type": "Generic"
    }
],
  "title": "x",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "Regular",
  "thread_path": "x"
}
```

I want to merge "messages" array from all the files into one "messages" array.

I got to this point(right now it kinda merges only two, but main point is here):

```
import json

with open('messages_1.json') as json_file:
    messages1 = json.load(json_file)

with open('messages_2.json') as json_file:
    messages2 = json.load(json_file)

a = messages1["messages"]
b = messages2["messages"]

a.append(b)

print(a)
```

But the problem is that I get:

```
[{messages1}, [{messages2}]]
```

when I want:

```
[{messages1}, {messages2}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use extend instead of append

Comment: didn't think about that, worked flawlesly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
import json

with open('messages_1.json') as json_file:
    messages1 = json.load(json_file)

with open('messages_2.json') as json_file:
    messages2 = json.load(json_file)

a = messages1["messages"]
b = messages2["messages"]

a.extend(b)

print(a)
```

It should do what you want to do :)